# Got Server Error 500 for web project which was downloaded from git

Tags: laravel, git, web

I made a project on GIT. It executes fine on my computer. But when I push it to GIT and my friends pull it, they can't execute it. They got this error-

> Server Error (500)

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf6Pj.png)

I found a lot of solutions on the Internet but nothing worked, so I have to ask on here. I use Wampserver, Sublime Text, Laravel for this project.

Comment: try looking up storage/logs/laravel.log file for error

Comment: Don't forget to copy the .env variable and edit the settings accordingly.

Comment: @Kerel thank you so much! I solved it. I can't believe that I got that small mistake. But i don't know why git doesn't push that file with my project?

Comment: you never want to have .env pushed to git because it contains your database credentials and app key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually copy the .env variable file and edit the settings accordingly. 
It's listed as a standard in the .gitignore file because you don't want to upload the credentials in there to a VCS.